# Adding attributes to a name list erases the names of that list

Tags: r, attributes

Simple question based on an unexpected behavior I observed.  I have a named list in R on which I add attributes with the `attributes<-` call.  This erases the name of the list.  Why and how can I prevent that?

ex:

```
ll <- list(a=1:4, b="der")
str(ll)
List of 2
 $ a: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
 $ b: chr "der" 

attributes(ll) <- list(attr1 = "my_attr")
 str(ll)
List of 2
 $ : int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
 $ : chr "der"
 - attr(*, "attr1")= chr "my_attr"
```

There are no names anymore.

I can get them back doing this:

```
names(ll) <- c("a", "b")
str(ll)
List of 2
 $ a: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
 $ b: chr "der"
 - attr(*, "attr1")= chr "my_attr"
```

However I would like not to have to record the names before and reapply them after.  I have a feeling the original names are an attribute that gets overwritten by `attributes<-` call.  Any idea how to get over that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this (i.e., setting a single new attribute, or modifying an existing one, while leaving existing attributes in place) is exactly what `attr()<-` is for:

```
> attr(ll,"attr1") <- "my_attr"
> ll
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4

$b
[1] "der"

attr(,"attr1")
[1] "my_attr"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `attributes`:

> Assigning attributes first removes all attributes, then sets any `dim`
>   attribute and then the remaining attributes in the order given: this
>   ensures that setting a dim attribute always precedes the `dimnames`
>   attribute.

I think capturing names beforehand may indeed be the only way, if you must use `attributes`. But I would  consider changing the attribute with a more targeted function, if possible. What are you trying to set?

You may for instance consider adding a `comment`. See the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/comment).

Comment: I have a workflow of complex home made functions.  90% of the functions requires 2 common simple arguments.  I wanted to have these arguments follow the output object.  Normally I would have done that with list and a `$call` element, but changing all my function to output lists would have been complicated.  I thought attributes would work and be easier it implement.

Comment: didn't know about comments, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to add `attributes` to an existing object is to do:

```
attributes(ll) <- append(attributes(ll), list(attr1 = "my_attr"))
```

This is more robust as it works for attributes in `list` AND in `data.frame` and requires only one row.